# How to use css in Laravel

Tags: css, laravel

Laravel noob here.

Laravel comes default using scss, but is there a simple way to use plain css. I changed the name of the files, and folder to css, but the css is rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your custom stylesheets, just put them inside of `public/css` folder and import them into html like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/my_style.css') }}">`